# How to change the directory defining mapped traits

Tags: enthought, traitsui

With the following definition

```
trait = Trait('default',{key1 : val1, key2 : val2, ...})
```

is it possible to change afterwards the dictionary associating traits and their mapped counterparts? This would allow to have an object-wise mapping and not a class-wise mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is 'yes'. Consider the following program:

```
from traits.api import HasTraits, Trait
from traitsui.api import View

class A(HasTraits):
    a = Trait(0,{0 : 'Zero', 1 : 'One'})

a = A()

a.configure_traits(view=View('a','a_'))
```

When run, you have a drop box with 0 and 1 and the corresponding text below.
It suffices to enter:

```
a.trait('a').handler.map = {0: 'new Zero', 1: 'new One'}
```

to have the new mapping